# how to alter drupal-6 view-2 query

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to update view query using drupal hook_views_pre_execute().
It's updating the query properly but even my query returning only couple of record, in view page it's showing pagination at the bottom but i've set the page limit 10. Can any one advise me how to resolve this issue.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view)
{ 
  switch($view->name)
  {
      case 'test_merchandise':
            $view->build_info['query'] = "MY QUERY";
            drupal_set_message($view->build_info['query']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to alter views query then use this method

```
function modulename_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){

    if ( $view->name == 'test_merchandise' ) {
        //here you will get the whole $query object and alter only the place you want change
        $query->orderby[0] = "substring(node_data_field_date_field_date_value,1,4) DESC";
        echo "<pre>";print_r($query);echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That hook really helped me a lot not only to solving the problem that i was facing but also to understand the structure of view  by printing it.

Comment: According to the [drupal views api docs](https://api.drupal.org/comment/33563#comment-33563) this hook must be placed in a file named MODULE.views.inc, and you may need to add `hook_views_api()` into your .module file.